# Need to copy multiple cells in the same row of data from one sheet to another when a Checkbox is checked

Tags: excel, checkbox, copy

I have a Spreadsheet that has two Sheets: Main and Backup. Both simply have 2 columns of data. Firstname is A, Lastname is B. Main has all the actual data: Currently just row 2 and 3 for testing.

I need to have a checkbox in each row (Likely in column C) that when it is checked the data in these cells is copied to the Backup sheet in the first currently open row, and if unchecked it removes the data from the Backup sheet.

eg. Checkbox in C2 is checked, which causes the data in A2 and B2 to copy to first available A2 and B2 row in Backup.

I have researched this and every example I can find slightly works to just copy the data, but can't delete it if the checkbox is unchecked, and can't figure out when data is already there.

Thank you!

I would like to do this without Macros if possible

I created this Macro using basic select, copy, and paste for specific cells, and it does copy the data when the box is checked. However a couple of things:

1. When I check the checkbox and it copies the data, it then switches my view to that sheet. I need it to do it behind the scenes. I'm guessing it is the Select lines causing this but I'm not too familiar with this.
2. I need it to delete that data if the checkbox is unchecked. So if the user accidentally checks the wrong checkbox and they uncheck it, it removes the data.
3. I need this to be able to figure out that if A2 and B2 of the destination sheet already has data, paste this onto the next available row.